# Keycloak theme not updating for the realms login from applications

Tags: keycloak

I have a KeyCloak 12.0.2 application running on docker. Now I am trying to update the themes for login screens for the Realms. Whenever I go and change the theme from Realm theme setting -
UC1 - Open KeyCloak instance, the properly selected theme login page will appear. No issues!
UC2 - Open my application, click login, and the login page will have KeyCloak theme always, even though I tried selecting the different theme for a master or the specific Realm.

This is the theme which is appearing on my login screen whenever I go here from any application which is configured to use KeyCloak as SSO, its regardless of which theme I select from the Realm setting always-

[image]

I have checked and configured on the KeyCloak login screen, the theme will change as per the selection of themes for the Master realm -

[image]

I have made changes into the standalone.xml file related to the theme cache as follows -

```
<theme>
  <staticMaxAge>-1</staticMaxAge>
  <cacheThemes>false</cacheThemes>
  <cacheTemplates>false</cacheTemplates>
  <welcomeTheme>${env.KEYCLOAK_WELCOME_THEME:keycloak}</welcomeTheme>
  <default>${env.KEYCLOAK_DEFAULT_THEME:keycloak}</default>
  <dir>${jboss.home.dir}/themes</dir>
</theme>
```

I am kind of stuck here as I have to add multiple themes based on the Realms I have in the KeyCloak. I also tried to restart the container in which KeyCloak is running but no luck.

Answer (score 36):

After lots of digging, I found out that I was changing the theme in the wrong place. To update the theme of the SSO login page, you need to select the theme using - Realm -> Clients -> Appropriate Client Name -> Theme.

[image]

If you try to change the theme using Realm -> Realm Settings ->Themes, only the login screen for the Admin console will change.

Comment: What just that, that explains when I try to reproduce locally I had no luck

Comment: Holy crap, I've had this issue for 3 years. We ended up overlaying the 'keycloak' theme (not ideal), but with breaking changes in 12, driving me to finding a solution finally. Thank you!

Comment: @Pratap Singh This doesn't work for me either. Did you put your theme in a jar-file or just copied it in the themes folder?

Comment: @GreenEyedAndy I am just copying the files inside the themes folder with appropriate folder name. Folder structure will look like- themes- name of theme-login

Comment: @Pratap Singh thank you for your answer. Meanwhile it is partial working but still having problems. I've opened a question here on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75458926/keycloak-theme-doesnt-show-up