# Keycloak Theme doesn't show up

Tags: themes, keycloak

Keycloak 20.0.0.2
I tried to make a custom login theme where I just change the background image to my own.

- I took the official documentation - it doesn't work.
- I looked a youtube video and do the stuff they do - it doesn't work.
- I cleared the cache - it doesn't work.
- I set the theme for the client - it doesn't work.
- I chown the whole custom theme directory to user and group keycloak - it changes nothing.

The only thing working is changing the parent from base to keycloak - I can see the change after refreshing the page.

This is what I have done so far:
I created a directory `mycustom/login` in the **keycloak/themes** directory.
I created a `theme.properties` file in the `mycustom/login` dir with the following content:

```
parent=keycloak
import=common/keycloak

styles=web_modules/@fontawesome/fontawesome-free/css/icons/all.css web_modules/@patternfly/react-core/dist/styles/base.css web_modules/@patternfly/react-core/dist/styles/app.css node_modules/patternfly/dist/css/patternfly.min.css node_modules/patternfly/dist/css/patternfly-additions.min.css css/login.css css/styles.css
```

Than I created a `resources` directory in the `mycustom/login` directory and in this `resources` dir I created a `css` and an `img` dir.
I put a styles.css with the following content in the `css` dir - which is the same as in the server developer guide from keycloak instead of the image name:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../img/Ambient_6.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And at last I put my `Ambient_6.jpg` in the `img` dir.
I then set the `mycustom` theme in the Realm->Themes for the `Login theme`.
As a test I also set my theme for the client login theme directly.

It doesn't matter what I do - I always see the `keycloak-bg.png` image if `parent=keycloak`.
If I set `parent=base` I see my image but there is, of course, no styling on the controls.

How can I make the `parent=keycloak` setting work with my background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the styles.css file.
For the Base-theme body->background-image is ok, but for the keycloak-theme you must use this style:

```css
.login-pf body {
  background-image: url('../img/Ambient_6.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not putting `import=common/keycloak` in the `theme.properties`?

I did the same steps as you, except including `import=common/keycloak`, and it works for me